# jQuery using .val() to check a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the radio button

```
<label>Bug Type</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="bugtype2" value="Defect">Defect</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="bugtype2" value="Issue">Issue</label>
```

I have a variable

```
var bugtype=$("#aa5").html();
alert(bugtype);
```

When I alert it, I'm getting a value of

```
Defect
```

I'm using the code

```
$("input:radio[name=bugtype2]:checked").val(bugtype);
```

but it doesn't check the radio button Defect, but the value of var bugtype is the same with the value of the radio button bugtype2

Comment: What is `aa5`? And the code `$("input:radio[name=bugtype2]:checked")` seems to suggest the radio button is already checked. I am confused by this question.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to get the value of which button is active?

Comment: What I want is for the radio button name=bugtype2 to check the value depending on the val(bugtype)

Answer (score 3):

Update your selector:

```
$('input[name=\'bugtype2\'][value="'+bugtype+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

If you have superfluous whitespace in the `#aa5` element, it might be prudent to use `$.trim()` on `bugtype` as follows:

```
$('input[name=\'bugtype2\'][value="'+$.trim(bugtype)+'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dydq4n1a/)

Comment: Was just about to comment that I thought `attr` should only be used to set the initial value of checked and `prop` everything else but you fixed it.

Comment: Well, technically `attr()` is the method to use for jQuery `<= 1.5`.

Comment: Oh ok, I knew it was a "somewhat" recent addition.

Comment: Sir may I ask again? What if its a dropdown now?

Comment: @Chong That is a separate question. Please ask it as another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='bugtype2'][value='" + bugtype + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nzyoyjw2/) fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `val()` to set whether a radio/checkbox is selected/checked.

`val()` sets or gets the value of some form elements.

Try:

```
$("input:radio[value='Defect']").attr('checked', true);
```

To explain the behaviour where you're seeing `Defect` after running:

```
var bugtype = $("#aa5").html();
alert(bugtype);
```

When you get multiple results for a selector, as is the case with `$("#aa5")`, when you call `.html()` you'll get back the HTML for the first selection.